# Archive-posttype.php isn't loaded

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I created a custom post type

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_packaged');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_packaged() {
register_post_type('packaged', array(
'label' => 'Packaged Foods',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'packaged-foods-list', 'with_front' => false ),
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','post-formats'),
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','pf_cat','pf_groc_cat'),
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Packaged Foods',
  'singular_name' => 'Packaged Food',
  'menu_name' => 'Packaged Foods',
  'add_new' => 'Add Packaged Food',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Packaged Food',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Packaged Food',
  'new_item' => 'New Packaged Food',
  'view' => 'View Packaged Food',
  'view_item' => 'View Packaged Food',
  'search_items' => 'Search Packaged Foods',
  'not_found' => 'No Packaged Foods Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Packaged Foods Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Packaged Food',
)
) ); }
```

and two taxonomies called pf_cat and pf_groc_cat

I am trying create a custom post type archive template and it always default to the archive.php

Here are the taxonomies:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_pf_cat');
function cptui_register_my_taxes_pf_cat() {
register_taxonomy( 'pf_cat',array (
  0 => 'packaged',
),
array( 'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'PF Categories',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'labels' => array (
  'search_items' => 'PF Category',
  'popular_items' => '',
  'all_items' => '',
  'parent_item' => '',
  'parent_item_colon' => '',
  'edit_item' => '',
  'update_item' => '',
  'add_new_item' => '',
  'new_item_name' => '',
  'separate_items_with_commas' => '',
  'add_or_remove_items' => '',
  'choose_from_most_used' => '',
)
) ); 
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_pf_groc_cat');
function cptui_register_my_taxes_pf_groc_cat() {
register_taxonomy( 'pf_groc_cat',array (
  0 => 'packaged',
),
array( 'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'PF Grocery Categories',
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'packaged-foods' ),
'show_admin_column' => false,
'labels' => array (
  'search_items' => 'PF Grocery Category',
  'popular_items' => '',
  'all_items' => '',
  'parent_item' => '',
  'parent_item_colon' => '',
  'edit_item' => '',
  'update_item' => '',
  'add_new_item' => '',
  'new_item_name' => '',
  'separate_items_with_commas' => '',
  'add_or_remove_items' => '',
  'choose_from_most_used' => '',
)
) ); 
}
```

I am new to CPT and Taxonomies and I'm really struggling here.  I read another question here about something very similar and he was requested to try the URL with the custom post type in it

http://[websitehere].com/?post_type=packaged uses the archive-packaged.php template.
http://[websitehere].com/?post_type=packaged&packaged-foods=organic-wines also works.

But, when I try http://[websitehere].com/packaged-foods/organic-wines/ it defaults to the archive.php

What in the heck do I have wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you make a change, of any kind, that will affect the URL layout of the site, you *must* flush the rewrite rules one time.

Easiest way to do this: In the wp-admin, visit the Settings->Permalinks page. You don't even have to save changes, just load that page.

The act of loading the Permalinks page causes the rewrite rules to be flushed and rebuilt. Since your CPT is now active, it will be included in the new rules that will be built and saved to the database.

Edit: Sorry, I misread your original problem.

It seems that you're wanting it to use the "archive-packaged.php" template with the URL of `http://[websitehere].com/packaged-foods/organic-wines/`.

The reason this isn't working is because "packaged-foods" is a taxonomy, not your custom post type. See, archive-* templates work with CPTs. Taxonomy templates fall under the taxonomy-* templates. And your pretty URL here doesn't specify a custom post type at all.

Use the taxonomy-pf_groc_cat.php template instead.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I stated that I flushed the rewrite rules as instructed.

Comment: Edited my post to have more info.

Comment: Thanks, you explained it perfectly and my template is now activated as I needed.!!!